# PlotlyRequestError: Authentication credentials were not provided python

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to do some visualizations using plotly.
But when I'm trying to do the visualizations I always get the following error.

[image]

Following is my code.

```
#Boxplot and histogram of Total Direct Variable Cost grouped by with or with Financial Class
import chart_studio.plotly as py

from  plotly.offline import iplot
trace0 = go.Box(
    y=healthcare.loc[healthcare['A'] == 'Inpatient']['B'],
    name = 'Inpatient',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgb(214, 12, 140)',
    )
)
trace1 = go.Box(
    y=healthcare.loc[healthcare['A'] == 'InBorn']['B'],
    name = 'InBorn',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgb(0, 128, 128)',
    )
)
data = [trace0, trace1]
layout = go.Layout(
    title = "CCCCCCCCCCCC"
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Do you mind to add a full [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Then are you still using `python2`? Consider that from version 4.0 plotly is offline only so you don't need to call `plotly.offline` anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, so I changed `py.iplot(fig)`  to `fig.show()`

Answer (score 0):

Read this: https://plotly.com/python/troubleshooting/

For Jupyter Classic Notebooks:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default='notebook'
```

Then use fig.show() as mentioned above.